# Connecting to azure through SQL crashes it

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure

I've been attempting to migrate from my own MSSQL to Azure Database services.
I got all the firewall things working and the database running on the azure, but when I try to connect through the local pc it crashed with an unknown exception.
So does visual studio.

Any ideas what could cause this unknown error?

Heres a picture demonstrating the crash and its not a user/password error. Just not.
[image: the damn bug]

Comment: Well, with the given depth of information (almost none) it would surprise me if anyone could say anything useful.

Comment: Thats because I have no information to give. I am as clueless as any. There is no error messages, no nothing. I am accepting suggestions

Comment: What does the error say? the part that is not in English?

Comment: It says unexpected error

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's better if you try to provide the Exception/Error code. You can use:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff394106.aspx

I had similar problems and in the end it turns to be the connection I've used - so one option is to restart your LAN/Network.

Update: According to me is config related error, please see these solutions here:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/runtime-error-p6025-pure-virtual-function-call-on/89e10d2f-b949-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5

https://superuser.com/questions/628314/runtime-error-r6025-unable-to-see-location-of-program-causing-the-error

About SSL certificate and Browser you're using:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=133476

http://www.symantec.com/connect/forums/r6025-pure-virtual-function-call-runtime-error

Maybe you've missed something, also what Win are you with?